# how to get the back data from a django view using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

my ajax is :

```
$('#save').click(function(){
            $.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/sss",
           function(data){
             alert(data);
           });
            })
```

and the django view is :

```
def sss(request):
    return HttpResponse('ddddddddddd')
```

how to get some data from the view 'sss'

thanks

Comment: Aren't you getting the data using this code?

Comment: What's the issue with the above code? What's not working?

Comment: my ajax is in the domain 127.0.0.1:8000  not 8080 , 8080 is my another django site

Comment: So your AJAX is being served from http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and your Django site is running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ ?  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a hack to do cross domain scripting is to read the data in using urlopen and returning the data you receive

while on domain1

```
import urlllib2

def getdata(req)
    redirectstr = "http://domain2.com/call/that/returns/data/"
    #make call to domain2
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(redirectstr)
    return HttpResponse( resp.whatever() )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running into a [cross domain issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You cannot perform ajax calls to different domains. You could use [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead (look at the Flickr example in the documentation, it demonstrates a cross domain ajax request). Your server needs to send data as JSONP string:

```
def sss(request):
    return HttpResponse('someCallbackName({ Data = 12345 })')
```

where `someCallbackName` should be dynamic and passed as request parameter. An important note is that JSONP works only with `GET` methods and not `POST`.